# Find matches within an Excel array formula result

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I am looking for a way do some kind of nested/indirect lookup.

1. I have a table of two columns with car models (e.g. Mustang) in column A and their makes (e.g. Ford) in column B
2. In column F I have a list of car models. This can be models that are listed in column A, but not all models of column A have te be listed in F
3. Column D contains some car makes.

For each car make in column D I need to determine whether there exists a model that is present in column F. So with the car make in a of D, I want to look up the corresponding care models in column B and next I want to look for occurrences of these found care models in column F.

I succeed to do the first lookup using an array formula, however I am stuck on how to determine whether the resulting array and the range in F have common elements (or a non-empty intersection).

Any help will be appreciated!

henkgijsbert

A(Model)   B(Make)    C(empty)   D(=Make2)   E(=Found)   F(=carlist)
Corvette    Chevrolet                    Dodge           (1)?             
Corvette
Camaro    
Chevrolet           
                
Chevrolet
    (2)?              Mustang
Mondeo     Ford                                                                    
Camaro
Mustang    Ford
Challenger Dodge
Avenger       Dodge

In the example above, on (1) the result should be N, because there are care no models in column F of the make D1 ("Dodge"). On (2) the result should be Y, because there are models (even 2) in column F of the  make D2 ("Chevrolet").

I have the following array-formula gets all models for the Make "Dodge" in D1:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$6; SMALL(IF(D1=$B$1:$B$6; ROW($A$1:$A$6);""); ROW()));"")}
```

How can I compare the result of this array-formula with matches in column F?

Comment: Can you share some data, expected result and your current formula?

Comment: Hey @QHarr, I added an example and the array-formula I already have. I hope I made it more clear now.

Comment: Why do you take the smallest value, i.e. `SMALL(`? It will take the first result in the Model list given it has found any value in Make. So if you want to find Mustang the SMALL will return Mondeo, since that row comes first (has the smallest value to return...) just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enter the following in E3 and drag down. Enter formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Enter</kbd> i.e. as an array formula.

```
 =IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(MATCH($F$3:$F$5,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D3,$B$3:$B$8)),$A$3:$A$8,""),0)))>0,"Y","N")
```

Data:

[image]

Comment: This one does not work because it does not sum the hits: enter Ford instead of Chevrolet in column D and you will see it (Mustang is a Ford, so your formula should return Y but it will say N).

Comment: F4 is Mustang, which is a Ford, so it is in the list.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to lookup the make into column G, you can use this formula:

```
=IF(0<SUM(MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE($A$2:$A$7)=$F$2:$F$3),--($B$2:$B$7=$D2))),"Y","N")
```

But I would recommend to create a Make2 column in G, that would be much easier to understand later.

Comment: Note: Later, if you want to know how many times the the make occurs in F, you just have to take the SUM(...) part.

Comment: Thank you @z32a7ul! Your answer also works, but I found QHarr 's answer easier to understand.